# Change the look of angular component based on where component is called from

Tags: node.js, angular, forms

I have a component that does one thing. Update the phone number through a modal view form.
I want to use the same component on a different page but the original look does not match the new page. I don't want it as a modal, etc

How can I use angular to display the component differently based on which component is calling it but keep the function the same?

Comment: sounds like you should take the contents of the modal and make its own component, then use that component in the modal, as well as places where its not required to be a modal.

Comment: It's already a component but I get what you mean.  Unfortunately in this case, I want to change things like button, input field shape too. As I said, doesn't match the look of the new page